# Why does Google not accept my address for jobLocation in microdata?

Tags: structured-data

What is the problem with my code when tested with https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool?

I have tried to set up structured data for JobPosting and then added location. But i dont have an exact postal address: so no zip code and no street just a city.

```
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/JobPosting">
  <h2 itemprop="title">Data Analyst</h2>
    <span itemprop="description">
      <strong>Company:</strong>
      <span itemprop="hiringOrganization">  
        <span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
          <span itemprop="name">
            Euro London Banking and Finance Germany
          </span>
        </span>
      </span>
    </span>
    <p><strong>Location:</strong>
    <span itemprop="jobLocation">
        <span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">
            <span itemprop="address">
                <span itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
                    <span itemprop="addressLocality">Mycityname</span>
                </span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
    </p>
    <p><strong>Employment type:</strong>
      <span itemmprop="employmentType">
        Full-time
      </span>,
      <span itemprop="workHours">
        40 hours per week
      </span>
    </p>
    <p><strong>Base salary:</strong>
      <span itemprop="salaryCurrency">
        EUR
      </span>
      <span itemprop="baseSalary">
        35000
      </span>
    </p>
    <p><strong>Responsabilities:</strong></p>

    <ul itemprop="responsibilities">
        <li>a</li>
        <li>b</li>
        <li>c</li>
    </ul>



    <p><strong>Educational requirements:</strong>
      <span itemprop="educationRequirements">
        Bachelor&#39;s degree
      </span>
    </p>
    <p><strong>Experience requirements:</strong>
    <span itemprop="experienceRequirements">
      At least 2 years of working experience, however recent graduates with relevant technical knowledge and experience through 
      internships, etc. will also be considered
    </span>
    </p>
    <p><strong>Qualifications:</strong></p>
      <ul itemprop="qualifications">
        <li>Profound knowledge of SQL Server and relational databases</li>
        <li>Profound knowledge of Visual Basic for Applications</li>
        <li>Profound knowledge of Microsoft Excel and Access</li>
        <li>Knowledge in ASP.Net and HTML is preferred</li>
        <li>Fluent in English; knowledge of the German language is preferred but not a must</li>
      </ul>
    <p><strong>Skills:</strong></p>
      <ul itemprop="skills">
        <li>Good analytical skills</li>
        <li>Good communication and interpersonal skills</li>
        <li>Ability to work in teams</li>
        <li>Stress resilient, goal-oriented and efficient</li>
      </ul>
    <p><strong>Date posted:</strong>
      <span itemprop="datePosted">
        2011-11-29
      </span>
    </p>
</div>
```

To me it seems that I can have text value for addres property. that is also what schema.org says. still it does not get verified :(

Comment: Could you simplify your example to just the address that is not being validated?

Comment: it is not just the address but the address implemented into the jobposting itemtype, which has its own requirements again.

Comment: Hmm OK. Sounds like you've already checked that the address is validating in other contexts. And you've read the Google structured data spec well. This might be something hidden behind closed-doors in Google's own processing. Suggest raising a support ticket with them and include evidence that the address is valid and links to their spec that says it can be included. That will help them debug.

Comment: So you really think it maybe an error on googles side? I suppose there is no possibility to open a support ticket with google though.

Comment: I'm saying if you've genuinely proven that the same address is accepted in the exact same form when supplied as part of other data types. And all the other details of your jobposting are being accepted. And Google's documentation states that it does accept an address as part of a jobposting. And you've linted the markup to check it does not contain errors. Then you have indeed debugged to the deepest level that you can possibly go and must conclude there is a bug further down the chain. You can raise support tickets with Google but they hide it away.

Answer (score 2):

Use itemprop and itemtype in the same span

```
<span itemprop="jobLocation" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">
    <span itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
        <span itemprop="addressLocality">Mycityname</span>
    </span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Place type can accept Text as well as a postalAddress type (http://schema.org/address) therefore you can do the following as a minimum and still be valid:

```
 "jobLocation": {
      "@type": "Place",
      "address": "Central City"
 }
```

I just tested it and although you will get warnings, you will get no errors.